# Tensor product notation

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus

In the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN7x5.png) there is a tensor product:

$$F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=2(B^2-\frac{E^2}{c^2})$$

It's about how this operation on the co- and contravariant field strength tensors can give one of the invariants of the electromagnetic field.

I've tried it and it's actually the double inner product, F_lower(row,column)*F^upper(column,row) summed over all rows and columns

$$F_{\mu \nu}F^{\nu \mu}$$

Is this the way I would write it with subscript summation?

How did it come?

Comment: The difference between $F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}$ and $F_{\mu \nu}F^{\nu \mu}$ is a sign because $F_{\mu \nu}$ is antisymmetric.

Answer (score 3):

You should be contracting the following two objects
$$
F_{\mu \nu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & E_x & E_y & E_z \\
-E_x & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\
-E_y & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\
-E_z & -B_y & B_x & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{and}\quad 
F^{\mu \nu} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -E_x & -E_y & -E_z \\
E_x & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\
E_y & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\
E_z & -B_y & B_x & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Some of the tensor components change signs when you move the indices around.  Now you should be doing what was mentioned by Fabian
$$
\sum_{\mu=0}^{3}\sum_{\nu=0}^{3}F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}=F_{00}F^{00}+F_{01}F^{01}+...+F_{33}F^{33}
$$
As you can see, the electric field multiplication will come out with an overall minus, and the magnetic field will come out positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as
$$\sum_{\mu=0}^3 \sum_{\nu=0}^3 F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}.$$
It is usually not written because of lazyness and shortness of notation (this notation is called [Einstein summation convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Comment: I just realized that two sources I was looking at have different definitions of the double inner product.  For example, http://www.foamcfd.org/Nabla/guides/ProgrammersGuidese3.html and http://people.rit.edu/pnveme/EMEM851n/constitutive/tensors_rect.html Which one is it supposed to be?

Comment: I don't see a difference, if I compare (1.15) with `Double Dot Product'. In any case, it should have the form in my answer.

Comment: I believe you, but on this picture http://people.rit.edu/pnveme/EMEM851n/constitutive/tensor_rect11.gif the formula flips the row and column on the second tensor. Do you know where that derivation comes from?

Comment: If the matrices are [ 1 -1; 1 1] and [1 -1; 1 1] then your equation gives A00B00+A01B01+A10B10+A11B11 = 4. The equation A00B00 + A01B10 + A10B01 + A11B11 = 1 -1 -1 +1 =0. The second equation is what's given in http://people.rit.edu/pnveme/EMEM851n/constitutive/tensor_rect11.gif

Comment: @Robert: there are different ways to contract tensors (i.e., make inner products). The second choice is written as $F_{\mu\nu} F^{\nu\mu}$.